# Declaration syntax error in FILE *fp (TURBO C++)

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I am using turbo c++. I am getting the error "Declaration Syntax error" in FILE *fp;
the following is my code.

```
#include <bios.h>
#include <dos.h>
FILE *fp;
unsigned char buf[512];
unsigned char st[60];
unsigned char headno[10];
unsigned char secno[10];
unsigned char trackno[10];
void main (void)
{
    int i ;
    for (i=0;i<512;i++)
        buf[i]=0;
    gets(st);
    fp=fopen(st,"wb");
    printf("Head ");
    gets(headno);
    puts (headno);
    printf("\nsector ");
    gets(secno);
    puts(secno);
    printf("\ntrack ");
    gets(trackno);
    puts(trackno);
    i = biosdisk(2,0x80,atoi(headno),
    atoi(trackno),atoi(secno),1,buf) ;
    if (*(((char *)(&i))+1)==0)
    {
        fwrite(buf,1,512,fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        printf("Cannot Read Error# = %x",i);
}
```

The error is shown in the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtwRc.png)

Comment: **In 2021 TurboC is obsolete. Use a better compiler** (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ..., or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) as your editor, and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) as your debugger. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop, since it has both

Comment: Also, **`gets` should never be used** (it is dangerous and prone to buffer overflow). Use `fgets` instead. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: If you are developing some OS kernel see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) and read before a [good operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FILE*`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/) and `fopen()` normally require you to `#include <stdio.h>`. I assume that is true for Turbo C++ too.